# OdbcCommand stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have problem with calling stored procedure from code.

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangePassword]
    @param1 sysname,
    @param2 sysname

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)
SET @sql = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @param1 + ' WITH PASSWORD = '''+ @param2 +'''';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END;
```

When I run this from SQL editor works fine, but when I call this from function:

```
        using (var command = new OdbcCommand("{call ChangePassword(?,?)}", connection))
        {
            try
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", user.Username);
                //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", user.password);

                command.Parameters.Add("@param1", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = user.Username;
                command.Parameters.Add("@param2", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = user.password;

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
```

I am getting error

```
ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'MYPASSWORD'.
```

near @param2

Please could someone help me with this.

I found way... :)

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangePassword]
    @param1 sysname,
    @param2 sysname

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500)
SET @sql = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + @param1 + ' WITH PASSWORD = '+ @param2 +'';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

END;
```

Work with these syntax :) but now when I run from SQL editor I have the same error that I have when called from function in previous version of stored procedure.

Could someone explain this?

edit

And the final is thanks to Marc Gravell:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChangePassword]
    @param1 sysname,
    @param2 sysname

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQL = N'ALTER LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@param1) + N' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@param2,'''');
EXEC(@SQL);

END;
```

Thanks

Comment: why not use double quote and put single quote inside? like "'" ?

Comment: Could you tell us what values you exactly use when using both the SQL editor and C#?

Comment: @JimRhodes Perhaps that's his password?

Comment: If (via your edit) my answer is "the answer" here, please consider marking it as such by clicking on the tick, rather than just copying it into the question

Answer (score 0):

I think the login should have double (') also..

```
'ALTER LOGIN ''' + @param1 + ''' WITH PASSWORD = '''+ @param2 +'''';
```

Comment: in SQL server, the `alter login <name>` does not accept the name as a string or parameter - it must be a direct object name (like with a table)

Comment: Try Print(@sql) and see what is the output. so you can debug it

Comment: answer i saw:
ALTER LOGIN yoursqllogin WITH PASSWORD = 'newpassword' OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpassword'

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use a mixture of different escape rules; the user-name needs to be `[]` escaped, and the password needs to be `'` escaped; neither can be parameterized in this case. Fortunately, `QUOTENAME` helps us here, for example:

```
-- this is just for example; this could be sp parameters etc
declare @username sysname = 'ab;drop table users;--',
        @password sysname = 'mwah''a''haha';

declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = N'alter login ' + QUOTENAME(@username)
    + N' with password = ' + QUOTENAME(@password, '''');

exec(@sql);
```

Note: I should note that this seems pretty odd as a requirement; I'd want to apply a little sanitization on the possible inputs too, personally (especially the username).